# ASP.Net - Wait until all Page Methods are not completed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.NET application and have one page in which all the server side processing are using Page Methods (Script Manager is available on page). 
Now the issue is that there are multiple Page Methods process asynchronously on server, some are taking 1~20 seconds, some are executed on success of other one but one of them takes 30 minutes approx.
Session timeout (20 min) and execution timeout (60 min) and working as expecting.

I have also a java-script function who checks the idle time on user and if user not taken any action until 20 min then a warning message appears and user will automatically logged out even one asynchronous request is still running behind.

Is there any way to check if any asynchronous request is still running? If yes then i will check on my java-script code who checks the idle time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to count the number of page methods that are currently running:

```
var callsRunning = 0;

function callPageMethod()
{     
      callsRunning += 1;
      PageMethods.DoSomething(onSucceed, onError);
      return false;
}   
function onSucceed(result)
{
      callsRunning -= 1;
      alert(result);        
}
function onError(result)
{      
      callsRunning -= 1;
}
```

So at any point you can check if `callsRunning > 0` to see if any methods are still being waited on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I believe the above solution will work for me, but i have used too many Page Methods so it will be very tedious job as i need to declare the variable "callsRunning" on every page. Is there any common way to utilize above throughout the application?

Comment: I would suggest having a MasterPage, which each of the individual pages uses.  Check out [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp).

Comment: But if i declare "callsRunning" in MasterPage then it will be global for all the other pages in my application. So if page1 increment it to 3 and if i opened Page2 into new tab then here the initial value will be 3. So we will never reached at callsRunning=0. And also on every page and on every Page Method i need to increment/decrement on success and initials.

Comment: That's not how master pages and javascript work.  The resulting merged page doesn't share DOM with other pages.  JavaScript runs in the browser and is only in scope for the current page.  You'll have one instance of callsRunning for every resulting page.